# Change AVPlayer video to reproduce clicking on a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I don't understand why the AVPlayer doesn't change the video when I click on a cell of a TableView that call the function of set another video stream to reproduce. Could you help me.
Here the code:

```
class VideoPlayerController: AVPlayerViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://live1.msf.ticdn.it/Content/HLS/Live/Channel(CH01HA)/Stream(03)/index.m3u8") else { return }
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    //player = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player?.play()
}

func setCanaleDaRiprodurre(url:String){
    let urlDaRiprodurre : URL? = URL.init(string: url)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: urlDaRiprodurre!)
        player?.pause()
        player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
        player?.play()
        print("Hello")
}
```

Here the code of TableViewController that call the function "setCanaleDaRiprodurre" with another stream URL.

```
override func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let  VideoPlayerController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "player") as! VideoPlayerController
    VideoPlayerController.setCanaleDaRiprodurre(url: menuItems[indexPath.row].stream_url!)
     }
```

Comment: AVPlayerItems can just be replaced?  You do not have to work with the layer or the view?  Several things look dangerous about this code too.  For example, the force unwrap `menuItems[indexPath.row].stream_url!` and that you are trying to reload an AVPlayerItem synchronously on the main thread.

Comment: I am so confuse because i can't understand my code doesn't work,  though i replace the 'AVPlayerItemes' synchronously on the main thread

Comment: Try rebuilding the view just to see if it does create a new player to see if the player plays the the stream.  Then work backwards for performance

Comment: when i call the function the player doesn't change the stream but it continue to reproduce the first video. I also change the code of the function to creare a new AvPlayer instead of change the AvPlayerItem but it doesn't work. At this point I suppose that the same instance is not called when I call the function in the TableViewController, maybe storyboard.istantiateViewController refer another instance of the AVPlayer??

Answer (score 0):

The `VideoPlayerController` in `didSelectRowAt:` is going out of scope before it has a chance to do anything.

Isn't your class *already* a `VideoPlayerController`? If you have a way of replacing the current channel, why not do this in `didSelectRowAt:`?

```
override func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.setCanaleDaRiprodurre(url: menuItems[indexPath.row].stream_url!)
}
```

For clarity you should avoid giving variables the same name as their classes, so instead of

```
let VideoPlayerController = ...
```

do something like

```
let  VideoPlayerController = ...
```

Comment: it doesn't work , i suppose that i point to another instance of AVPlayer, i can't understand how i can change the video to play.

Comment: it's hard to say without seeing more. can you link to a small project that reproduces the problem?